# How to use required_if Laravel Validation in php

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I want to give validation if weight is not empty then shipping_cost required and vise verse.

```
array('weight' => 'numeric|required_if:shipping_cost,value',
'shipping_cost' => 'numeric|required_if:weight,value')
```

What will be the value for 'weight,**value**' and  'shipping_cost,**value**' ?

Comment: Try `array('weight' => 'numeric|required_with:shipping_cost,
'shipping_cost' => 'numeric|required_with:weight')` This will make each of the fields require each other only if there is a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can use the required_if without a specific value.

You can use a condition for that.

```
$rules = [
    'weight' => ['numeric'],
    'shipping_cost' => ['numeric']
]

// Shipping costs requires weight, and weight requires shipping cost
if ( ! empty(Input::get('weight')) or ! empty(Input::get('shipping_cost')))
{
    $weight['shipping_cost'][] = 'required';
    $rules['weight'][] = 'required';
}
```